# C++ function does not exit at the end of main after return 0

Tags: c++, multithreading

I was implementing a multi-threading database using a thread pool. Everything was fine and the functions can execute all the codes before `return 0`.

However, the function does not end after the `return 0` in `main()`. I used `_Exit(0)` to force exit, which is not very nasty. I ran it with valgrind and there is no memory leak until the end of function.

[image: The image of the possible memleak]

As you might see in the picture, all the threads are detached, so I shouldn't be running into trouble with threads. But what could go run such that the program can't stop?

```
auto rwfunc = [](int &id,struct rwinfo &_rwinfo){ 
    Qtable.vec_qpvec[_rwinfo.tableid][id].iswriter? 
    Writer(id,_rwinfo):Reader(id,_rwinfo);};
//my lambda function to insert my function into the thread

this_thread::yield();
if (COPYFLAG){
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < Qtable.tablenum; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < info_vec[i].vecsize; ++j) {
            pool.push(rwfunc,j,info_vec[i]);
        }
    }
}
//pushing function into the pool
```

**Minimal reproducible example Definition and Thread pool**

```
#include <getopt.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <queue>
#include <functional>
//#pragma once
#include<thread>
#include<vector>
#include<queue>
#include<mutex>
#include<condition_variable>
#include<functional>
#include<future>
//////////////////////////
#define MAX_THREADS std::thread::hardware_concurrency() - 1;
bool EXITFLAG = false;
bool COPYFLAG = false;
//portable way to null the copy and assignment operators
#define NULL_COPY_AND_ASSIGN(T) \
    T(const T& other) {(void)other;} \
    void operator=(const T& other) { (void)other; }

/* ThreadPool class
It is a singleton. To prevent spawning
tons of threads, I made it a singleton */
class ThreadPool{
public:

    //getInstance to allow the second constructor to be called
    static ThreadPool& getInstance(int numThreads){
        static ThreadPool instance(numThreads);
        return instance;
    }
    void waitfinish(){
        for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; ++i) {

        }
        Pool.clear();
    }

    //add any arg # function to queue
    template <typename Func, typename... Args >
    inline auto push(Func&& f, Args&&... args){

        //get return type of the function
        typedef decltype(f(args...)) retType;

        //package the task
        std::packaged_task<retType()> task(std::move(std::bind(f, args...)));


        // lock jobqueue mutex, add job to the job queue
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(JobMutex);

        //get the future from the task before the task is moved into the jobqueue
        std::future<retType> future = task.get_future();

        //place the job into the queue
        JobQueue.emplace( std::make_shared<AnyJob<retType> > (std::move(task)) );

        //notify a thread that there is a new job
        thread.notify_one();

        //return the future for the function so the user can get the return value
        return future;
    }

    inline int getThreadCount(){
        return numThreads;
    }

private:

    //used polymorphism to store any type of function in the job queue
    class Job {
    private:
        std::packaged_task<void()> func;
    public:
        virtual ~Job() {}
        virtual void execute() = 0;
    };

    template <typename RetType>
    class AnyJob : public Job {
    private:
        std::packaged_task<RetType()> func;
    public:
        AnyJob(std::packaged_task<RetType()> func) : func(std::move(func)) {}
        void execute() {
            func();
        }
    };
    // end member classes

    //member variables
    int numThreads; // number of threads in the pool
    std::vector<std::thread> Pool; //the actual thread pool
    std::queue<std::shared_ptr<Job>> JobQueue;
    std::condition_variable thread;// used to notify threads about available jobs
    std::mutex JobMutex; // used to push/pop jobs to/from the queue
    //end member variables

    /* infinite loop function */
    inline void threadManager() {
        while (!EXITFLAG) {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(JobMutex);
            thread.wait(lock, [this] {return !JobQueue.empty(); });

            //strange bug where it will continue even if the job queue is empty
            if (JobQueue.size() < 1)
                continue;

            (*JobQueue.front()).execute();

            JobQueue.pop();
        }
        std::cerr<<"thread end!"<<std::endl;
    }

    /*  Constructors */
    ThreadPool(); //prevent default constructor from being called

    //real constructor that is used
    inline explicit ThreadPool(int _numThreads) : numThreads(_numThreads) {

        int tmp = MAX_THREADS;
        if(numThreads > tmp){
            numThreads = tmp;
        }

        Pool.reserve(numThreads);
        std::cerr<<"Thread pool core num: "<<numThreads<<std::endl;
        for(int i = 0; i != numThreads; ++i){
            Pool.emplace_back(std::thread(&ThreadPool::threadManager, this));
            Pool.back().detach();
        }
    }
    /* end constructors */


    NULL_COPY_AND_ASSIGN(ThreadPool);
}; /* end ThreadPool Class */
using namespace std;
int COUNTER = 0;
mutex id_mtx;

struct rwinfo{
    sem_t &FINISHED;
    rwinfo(sem_t &finished):
            FINISHED(finished)
    {}
};

void work_todo(int &id,struct rwinfo &_rwinfo){
    id_mtx.lock();
        cout<<"Job "<<id<<" is done."<<endl;
        COUNTER++;
        cerr<<"COUNTER is now : "<<COUNTER<<endl;
    if (COUNTER==10){
        sem_post(&_rwinfo.FINISHED);
    }
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(500ms);
    id_mtx.unlock();
}

ThreadPool& pool = ThreadPool::getInstance(8);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);

    sem_t FINISHED;
    sem_init(&FINISHED,1,0);

    auto mylambdafunc = [](int &i,struct rwinfo &_rwinfo){work_todo(i,_rwinfo);};

    auto A = rwinfo(FINISHED);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        pool.push(mylambdafunc,i,A);
    }
    cerr<<"Start waiting"<<endl;
    sem_wait(&FINISHED);
    cerr<<"wake up"<<endl;

    EXITFLAG = true;
    cerr<<"Leaving"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

***Main***

```
    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);

    sem_t FINISHED;
    sem_init(&FINISHED,1,0);

    auto mylambdafunc = [](int &i,struct rwinfo &_rwinfo){work_todo(i,_rwinfo);};

    auto A = rwinfo(FINISHED);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        pool.push(mylambdafunc,i,A);
    }
    cerr<<"Start waiting"<<endl;
    sem_wait(&FINISHED);
    cerr<<"wake up"<<endl;

    EXITFLAG = true;
    cerr<<"Leaving"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This example can sometimes stuck and sometimes return correctly. I guess it is because it is a lot less jobs to do and jobs are a lot faster.

Also,another question. I was writing a mutithreading database. Some queries will change the data table and some will not. I treated it as the classic reader writer problem and queued every query as a job into the job queue of the thread pool.

The strange thing is that, The program runs actually fastest when there is only 1 thread in the thread pool. When it has 8 threads, it works a lot slower. I'm sure that the thread number in the thread pool is at most `std::thread::hardware_concurrency() -1`

What could be the possible reason?

Comment: Use a debugger to see the stack trace of where the main thread is blocked.  Most likely it is in the destructor of some object (either a stack-object or a static-object), which is waiting for a thread to exit.

Comment: Don't put tags in the title. That's what tags are for.

Comment: Please create a [mcve].

Comment: *"[X] so, I shouldn't been running into trouble with threads."* -- I more definitive way to demonstrate this would be to comment out the line(s) that create new threads. If you run into the same issue when operating single-threaded, then there is definitely no trouble with threads. If you don't... well, that might bring into question your conclusion.

Comment: What does the `main()` function look like? Please provide a [mcve] that reproduecs the blockage in action.

Comment: Beware that your job queue is locked while jobs are being executed. Pushing jobs will block if the worker is busy which makes this system useless for multithreading. You should move the job out of the queue, pop the queue, unlock then finally execute the moved job.

Comment: If tour system needs `detach` then it is probably broken. Try to restructure such that you can `join` the threads. This may be related to your inability to return from main.

Comment: That strange bug looks like `JobMutex` is not always locked when pushing jobs to the queue.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux 'If tour system needs detach then it is probably broken. Try to restructure such that you can join', strongly disagree:(

Comment: 'used _Exit(0) to force exit'.... is there some problem with that approach?